# npm start used to work on my computer and now it doesn't

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-start

Long story short, I bought an enterprise (custom made) laptop that wouldn't allow me to use npm start, no matter what kind of upgrades I made on package.json files. My I.T. consultant who sold me the laptop recommened I reinstall node.js on an Administrator Account as I was initially using a User Account, and it worked!... But the next day I got the same stupid error message ***npm ERR! missing script: start*** And I didn't even change anything! What else could be causing this error???

Comment: Check your `package.json` is not changing for some reason, without start set in scripts section its not going to work. https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts. it has nothing to do with your os, or hardware

Comment: I already used those scripts in package.json and it still didn't work.